# Cannot convert from Function<Short, Object> to Function<Short, Short>

Tags: java, eclipse, function, java-8, short

So, this university exercise asks to write a method that takes as an argument a `Function<Short, Short>` and result type a `Function<Short, Short>`. It should return the outcome of the function divided by 9.
This is the code I wrote, and while I'm quite confident that it should be working, eclipse shows an error at line 16 that I simply don't understand:

```
"Type mismatch: cannot convert from Function<Short,Object> to Function<Short,Short>.
```

It works fine if I put `Function<Integer, Integer>` in both, or if I write `Function<Short, Object>` at the return type, and leave the argument as Function<Short, Short>.

```
public Function<Short, Short> ulmic(Function<Short, Short> period) {
   return period.andThen(a -> a / 9);
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order to make it work, you have to write as follows:

```java
public Function<Short, Short> ulmic(Function<Short, Short> period) {
    return period.andThen(a -> (short) (a / 9));
}
```

When you apply the operand, `/` over `a` and `9`, Java converts the result to an integer.

From [Chapter 5. Conversions and Promotions](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html) one can read:

> One conversion context is the operand of a numeric operator such as +
> or *. The conversion process for such operands is called numeric
> promotion. Promotion is special in that, in the case of binary
> operators, the conversion chosen for one operand may depend in part on
> the type of the other operand expression.

and [`5.6.2. Binary Numeric Promotion`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.6.2)

> When an operator applies binary numeric promotion to a pair of
> operands, each of which must denote a value that is convertible to a
> numeric type, the following rules apply, in order:
>
> If any operand is of a reference type, it is subjected to unboxing
> conversion ([§5.1.8](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.8)).
>
> Widening primitive conversion ([§5.1.2](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.2)) is applied to convert either or
> both operands as specified by the following rules:
>
> - If either operand is of type double, the other is converted to double.
> - Otherwise, if either operand is of type float, the other is converted
>   to float.
> - Otherwise, if either operand is of type long, the other is converted
>   to long.
> - Otherwise, both operands are converted to type int.